# AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin header - Help Needed

Tags: html, controls, amp-html

I Am trying for the 1st time implementing AMP for my website and getting this errors like

-- Response must contain the AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin header
-- Form submission failed: Error: Response must contain the AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin header​​​

I tried it before but did not work.

sorry PS since means http:// is not allowed i had to change link in code to http-mydomain.com

any help is appreciated. Thank You

```
    <code>      <form method="post"
  class="p2"
  action-xhr="//mydomain.com/limoz/mobile/chkfare.php"
  target="_top">
  <div class="ampstart-input inline-block relative m0 p0 mb3">
    <label>Pickup Address</label>
    <input type="text"
      class="block border-none p0 m0"
      name="caddr" id="caddr" required>
    <label>Drop-Off Address</label>
    <input type="text"
      class="block border-none p0 m0"
      name="cdest" id="cdest" required>
<label>Travel Date &amp; Time</label><br>
      <input type="date"
      class="block border-none p0 m0"
      name="csdate" id="csdate" required>

      <input type="time"
      class="block border-none p0 m0"
      name="cstime" id="cstime" required>
<label>No. of Passengers</label><br>
      <select name="csnop" id="csnop">
                  <?php for($x = 1;$x <= 20; $x++) { ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $x; ?>"><?php echo $x; ?> PAX</option>
                  <?php } ?>
                </select>


  </div>
  <div id="dfare"></div>
  <div id="map"></div><br><bR>
  <input type="submit"
    value="  Get Fare  ">
  <!--<div submit-success>
    <template type="amp-mustache">
      Success! Thanks {{name}} for trying the
      <code>amp-form</code> demo! Try to insert the word "error" as a name input in the form to see how
      <code>amp-form</code> handles errors.
    </template>
  </div>
  <div submit-error>
    <template type="amp-mustache">
      Error! Thanks {{name}} for trying the
      <code>amp-form</code> demo with an error response.
    </template>
  </div>-->
</form>
<?php if(!empty($_POST)){
        $domain_url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]";
        header("Content-type: application/json");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ". str_replace('.', '-','http-taxiwebsitedesigner.net') .".cdn.ampproject.org");
        header("AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin: " . $domain_url);
        header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers: AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin");
        header("AMP-Redirect-To: http-mydomain.com/limoz/mobile/chkfare.php");
        header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers: AMP-Redirect-To, AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin"); 
        echo json_encode(array('successmsg'=>'data post'));
        exit;
} ?></code>
```

Comment: make sure you are using `HTTPS` URL. Please refer https://ampbyexample.com/advanced/using_the_google_amp_cache/

Comment: Hello! Perhaps this will help: [https://gist.github.com/...](https://gist.github.com/alexandr-kazakov/f0529503ec09bb8415a0af5571de3906) 06 This is a working test of the amp-contact form. There are no errors. Words in Russian.